# Prisma binding unable to connect to prisma server. request to http://localhost:4466/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am running two separate docker services. One for my GraphQL server and the other one is a prisma service connecting to a local Postgres database. I am able to run prisma deploy and test it out directly in `http://localhost:4466`. But When I try to query using my app’s GraphQL server in `http://localhost:8080`, it gives the following response.

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "request to http://localhost:4466/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "feed"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the stack trace.

```
graphql-server_1  | [Network error]: FetchError: request to http://localhost:4466/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466
graphql-server_1  | Error: request to http://localhost:4466/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466
graphql-server_1  |     at new CombinedError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/errors.js:83:28)
graphql-server_1  |     at Object.checkResultAndHandleErrors (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/errors.js:101:15)
graphql-server_1  |     at CheckResultAndHandleErrors.transformResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/transforms/CheckResultAndHandleErrors.js:10:25)
graphql-server_1  |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/transforms/transforms.js:19:54
graphql-server_1  |     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
graphql-server_1  |     at applyResultTransforms (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/transforms/transforms.js:18:23)
graphql-server_1  |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/delegateToSchema.js:82:50
graphql-server_1  |     at step (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/delegateToSchema.js:32:23)
graphql-server_1  |     at Object.next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/delegateToSchema.js:13:53)
graphql-server_1  |     at fulfilled (/usr/src/app/node_modules/graphql-binding/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/delegateToSchema.js:4:58)
```

This is how I created the binding

```
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    db: new Prisma({
      typeDefs: './src/generated/prisma.graphql',
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:4466',
      secret: 'my-secret',
      debug: true,
    })
  })
});
```

I am not sure as to what is the problem.

Full Code can be found here: https://github.com/dhanushuUzumaki/Journal/tree/feature/setup

Comment: Shouldn't the GraphQL server endpoint be 8080?

Comment: I don't think so.. my app's GraphQL server is running on 8080 and prisma is running on 4466. The endpoint should point to prisma service right? When I query 4466 directly its working.. if I do it through 8080 I am facing this error.

Comment: Good edits, @tk3 `:-)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got Help from prisma forum to solve this.

Using localhost within a container points to the container itself and not the host on which the containers are running. So in order to connect to the Prisma instance, you have to use the internal service name which resolves to the respective Prisma container.

```
...
    db: new Prisma({
      typeDefs: './src/generated/prisma.graphql',
      endpoint: 'http://prisma:4466',
      secret: 'my-secret',
      debug: true,
    })
...
```

[Prisma Forum - ECONNREFUSED - Unable to connect to prisma service through binding](https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/prisma-binding-unable-to-connect-to-prisma-server-request-to-http-localhost-4466-failed-reason-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-4466/3516/3)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when using Docker Toolbox on windows, the endpoint had to be changed from using localhost to the VirtualBox default ip within `prisma.yml`:

```
endpoint: http://192.168.99.100:4466
```

Comment: 'ERR_INVALID_URL': Invalid URL: 192.168.99.100:4466

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked for me. Installing Prisma server to create a React + Prisma/GrapQL app following this tutorial: https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/build-react-graphql-app-with-fetch-ct19 on Windows 8.1 with Docker.

How do you know the VirtualBox IP? My VirtualBox network addresses are 192.168.56.1 and 192.168.99.1, but **192.168.99.100** was the address that worked to deploy prisma.